# How do I find that March 2nd and March 3rd falls between March 1st and March 4th?

Tags: grails, groovy

I need a way to find these in grails:

1) I have two dates say `start` and `end`.

2) User selects two dates in the browser say them `userStartDate` and `userEndDate`.

I have all these values, but I need to write a query that do find that both `start` and `end` falls between `userStartDate` and `userEndDate`.

For example, March 2nd and March 3rd falls between March 1st and March 4th. Given that :

March 2nd and March 3rd are `userStartDate` and `userEndDate` dates respectively

March 1st and March 4th are `start` and `end` respectively. (they are domain objects).

I have this code which works for **between** cases i.e `start` is in **between** `userStartDate` and `userEndDate` like so :

```
  test = Holiday.createCriteria().list {
            and {
                   user {
                       eq('username',username)
                   }
                   or {
                   between('start',userStartDate,userEndDate) 
                   between('end',userStartDate,userEndDate)
               }
            }
        }
```

As according to my question, how can attach that part into my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't the faintest idea what your are asking

Comment: I've explained how to check if a date is within a range in Groovy code. I've also explained how to do it in a criteria query. Unless I actually sit down at your desk and edit the code personally, I don't see how I can do much more for you

Comment: @Don : Literally sorry for the confusion. I want a reverse one, as I have edited my question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you already do a check that `userStartDate` is before `userEndDate` (validated when the user selects) and that `start` is before `end` in the database (validated when inserting), the criteria query should look something like this:

```
test = Holiday.createCriteria().list {
    user { eq('username',username) }
    lt('start', userStartDate)
    gt('end', userEndDate)
}
```

This checks that `start` is less than (i.e. before) `userStartDate` and that `end` is greater than (i.e. after) `userEndDate`. There is also no need to wrap in an `and` block since all clauses are implicitly and-ed.

Answer (score 2):

Date provides before and after methods (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)

```
if(start.after(userStartDate) && start.before(userEndDate))
{
  //start is between userStartDate && userEndDate
}
```

Comment: @Don Agree with you...i just didn't know groovy has that feature

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to figure out if one date is between two others is using a Range object

```
def start = new Date()
def end = new Date() + 10

// make a date range
def dateRange = start..end

// test if some dates are within the range
def inRange = new Date() + 5
def outsideRange = new Date() + 50    

assert inRange in dateRange
assert !(outsideRange in dateRange)
```

However, you mentioned that you want to compare dates in a query, so a Groovy solution may not be optimal. Here's an example for checking if someone's birthday is between 2 dates using a criteria query

```
def start = new Date()
def end = new Date() + 10

def results = User.withCriteria {
  between('birthday', start, end)
}
```

Comment: I have tried adding the `in` keyword in my query referring to this http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html, which throws an error!

Comment: The code you have given will just find whether one domain field is in between, I need to find whether **two** domain files are in between a range. Hope I'm clear to you.

Comment: @Ant's unfortunately you're not clear at all. The code above already checks whether 2 fields are within a range, the `start` field and the `end` field

Comment: Very sorry for the confusion. I want a reverse one! i.e `userStartDate`,`userEndDate` should fall within `start` and `end` field