# Grails 2.1 SQL to Grails GORM Query

Tags: controller, hql, grails-2.0

I want something like this

```
'SELECT * FROM MyDomain WHERE endDate >= date AND startDate <= date'

Now please give possible solution by this way

def date = new Date().clearTime(), 
obj = MyDomain.find(....................) or
obj = MyDomain.findWhere(....................)
```

but i do not want any sql or hql injection. Can anybody help me.I want this by GORM. Apology for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to use criteria in this case will be

```
def myDomainList = MyDomain.withCriteria{
   def date = new Date().clearTime()
   le('startDate', date)
   ge('endDate', date)
}
```

Please note the rectification:
The query demands less than equals and greater than equals, in which case 'le' and 'ge' has to be used in the criteria.

AND is implicit in criteria as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need yo write this

```
def myDate = new Date().clearTime()
obj = MyDomain.findAll("FROM MyDomain Where (:myDate) between startDate AND endDate", [myDate: myDate])
```

Or

```
obj = MyDomain.executeQuery("FROM MyDomain Where (:myDate) between startDate AND endDate", [myDate: myDate])
```

if you want to go for without sql or hql then go for criteria

```
 obj = MyDomain.createCriteria().list{

      and{
           lt('startDate', myDate)
           gt('endDate', myDate)
         }
}
```

for more information you can visit this [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518252/how-do-i-find-that-march-2nd-and-march-3rd-falls-between-march-1st-and-march-4th)

Comment: I think it will
obj = MyDomain.executeQuery("FROM MyDomain Where (:myDate) between startDate AND endDate", [myDate: myDate])
because of * sign will catch wrong

Comment: or 
obj = MyDomain.executeQuery("SELECT d.* FROM MyDomain d Where (:myDate) between d.startDate AND d.endDate", [myDate: myDate])